# Why I need to wrap the code in immediately invoked function expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, anonymous-function, jslint, strict

1) Why I need to wrap the below mentioned code in `(function(){})();` , otherwise it is throwing error during JS linting and 2) I will also receive error if placing `"use strict";` above `(function(){})();` what I thought is to put `"use strict";` at the very first line of page.

Please let me know about the two behaviors.

My Working code -

```
(function(){
"use strict";

// Constructing constructor function
// whose purpose is to create new 
// Person Objects
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name || "TestUser";
    this.hobbies = [];
};

Person.prototype.setHobby = function(hobby) {
    this.hobbies.push(hobby);
};

Person.prototype.getHobbies = function() {
    return this.hobbies;
};


exports.Person = Person;

var peter = new Person('peter');
peter.setHobby('Gambling');
peter.setHobby('Street Fighting');
peter.setHobby('Smoking');

peter.getHobbies();
})();
```

Comment: What jslint error are you getting? Are you using jslint (not recommended) or jshint (recommended)? If jshint, are you using /*jslint node: true */?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
/*jshint node: true */
```

at the top of your file. Even removing the IIFE, it then will pass jshint with flying colors.

I would not recommend jslint. You will spend the rest of your life fighting with it and tweaking your code to make it shut up.

Comment: Thumbs up for the solution, but I strongly disagree with disabling `jslint`(!). For instance, it is very useful when you are working in a team and you want everybody to stick to a certain code style. It's also easy to tweak what errors/warnings you want to be displayed (custom config file). The feature `unused variables` is also very handy... just my opinion.

Comment: I was not suggesting skipping linting. I was suggesting using a linter such as jshint or eslint which is not as opinionated and obnoxious as jslint.